# Dynamically adjust process CPU quota

Tags: linux, process, cpu-usage

In Linux is there a way to dynamically adjust the CPU quota for a process, from outside the process, while is running?

For example, I run a process with no limit. Then, while it is running, I manually set it to 50% quota. Later, I remove the 50% quota, letting it again run without limit.

Of course best solution would cover multi-processor usage, but I will accept a solution that requires pinning the process to a CPU.

I also will accept solutions that rely on systemd, although this isn't necessary.

Comment: Hint: `https://scoutapm.com/blog/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups`

Comment: Can you explain how you set the quota? Are you changing the process priority or are you actually setting quotas and, if so, how?